# will not generate barcode

Tags: python, barcode

I was trying to create a bar code generator in python using a fairly simple code. I am new to some this module and am a bit rusty to python so I was wondering what causes an error in the code

```
#imports the correct module needed to create the barcodes 
from barcode import EAN13
# imports a module that will create the numbers needed for the barcode
from random import randint

codes = []
barcodes = []
for i in range(100):
    code = randint(1111111111111, 9999999999999)
    while code not in codes:
        codes.append(code)

# creates the barcode object   
for code in codes: 
    barcode = EAN13("{codes}")
    barcodes.append(barcode)


# prints the barcode
print(barcodes(0))



Error caused
will not generate any barcodes because the number cant be saved as a string

i want this to be able to display barcodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ImageWriter to save as png files. Import and use when creating the barcode.

```
from barcode import EAN13
from random import randint
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

codes = []
barcodes = []
for i in range(100):
    code = randint(1111111111111, 9999999999999)
    while code not in codes:
        codes.append(code)

# creates the barcode object
for code in codes:
    code = str(code)
    # barcode = EAN13(code)
    barcode = EAN13(code, writer=ImageWriter())
    barcodes.append(barcode)

# render the first barcode in the list
# barcodes[0].render()

for bc in barcodes:
    bc.save(f'barcode{bc.ean}')
```

Comment: thank you burt this displays an error when running for some reason i am unable to open the png that was created

Comment: the error i got was a permission error: ermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'barcode7406502820659.png'

Comment: I think you need pillow installed to generate the images **pip install pillow** That may be your issue if you dont have it installed.

Comment: i did that and it was already satisfied

Comment: Permission denied suggests that file 'barcode7406502820659.png' exists and is already open in som app or the directory you are saving the pngs to doesn't exist or maybe cannot be written to. Since they are randomly generated the later seems more likely. Can you double check there is not issue with the directory you are trying to save in?

Comment: how do i know what directory i am saving it too?

Comment: That can depend on what IDE you are using. For most or if you are just running it as a python file in a command window it should be the same directory as the python file. You can specify the directory to be sure, like change the line to **bc.save(f'c:/Temp/bc/barcode{bc.ean}')** and make sure the directory exists before running the code.

Comment: I am using vs code and when runnging with this it throws this syntax error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: What line? the save line? Are you using backslashes for the path like 'c:\Temp\bc\barc...' If so you can sometimes get away with that but potentially a backslash will be interpreted as an escape character, e.g. the \b in the path would be considered to be a word boundary. That's why I used forward slashes (forward slashes will work for Windows, MACOS and Linux) . If you want to use back slashes then use the 'raw' attribute, r' i.e. **bc.save(fr'c:\Temp\bc\barcode{bc.ean}')** or use double backslash **bc.save(f'c:\\Temp\\bc\\barcode{bc.ean}')**